# "Not scheduling suspect block" spams hdfs datanode log

Tags: hbase, hdfs, dn

when checking a dn log, we found there were lots of logs as follows:

```
2016-07-01 05:53:29,328 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/data12/hadoop/dfs, DS-086bc494-d862-470c-86e8-9cb7929985c6): Not scheduling suspect block BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1095475173_21737939 for rescanning, because we rescanned it recently.
2016-07-01 05:53:29,330 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/data12/hadoop/dfs, DS-086bc494-d862-470c-86e8-9cb7929985c6): Not scheduling suspect block BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1095475173_21737939 for rescanning, because we rescanned it recently.
2016-07-01 05:53:29,334 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/data12/hadoop/dfs, DS-086bc494-d862-470c-86e8-9cb7929985c6): Not scheduling suspect block BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1095475173_21737939 for rescanning, because we rescanned it recently.
2016-07-01 05:53:29,340 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/data12/hadoop/dfs, DS-086bc494-d862-470c-86e8-9cb7929985c6): Not scheduling suspect block BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1095475173_21737939 for rescanning, because we rescanned it recently.
2016-07-01 05:53:29,342 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/data12/hadoop/dfs, DS-086bc494-d862-470c-86e8-9cb7929985c6): Not scheduling suspect block BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1095475173_21737939 for rescanning, because we rescanned it recently.
2016-07-01 05:53:29,344 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/data12/hadoop/dfs, DS-086bc494-d862-470c-86e8-9cb7929985c6): Not scheduling suspect block BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1095475173_21737939 for rescanning, because we rescanned it recently.
2016-07-01 05:53:29,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/data12/hadoop/dfs, DS-086bc494-d862-470c-86e8-9cb7929985c6): Not scheduling suspect block BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1095475173_21737939 for rescanning, because we rescanned it recently.
```

The exception stack trace looks like this:

```
2016-07-01 11:56:38,601 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(x.x.x.29:50010, datanodeUuid=f3d795cc-2b3b-43b9-90c3-e4157c031d2c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a99b693d-6f26-48fe-ad37-9f8162f70b22;nsid=920937379;c=0):encountered exception while serving BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1103265984_29531546 to /x.x.x.21:44153
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectlyInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:427)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferToDirectly(FileChannelImpl.java:492)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:607)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.transferToFully(SocketOutputStream.java:223)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.sendPacket(BlockSender.java:586)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.doSendBlock(BlockSender.java:769)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockSender.sendBlock(BlockSender.java:716)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.readBlock(DataXceiver.java:551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.opReadBlock(Receiver.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.Receiver.processOp(Receiver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:251)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We find that the blocks related with these logs have relations with the hbase rs, according to the logs, the rs tries to read the file.

So my question is that in which case the rs tries to read the file? seen from logs, the rs tries to initiate a new reading request once a second.

Any advices or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

The hbase reads blk_1105510536_31776579 repeatedly! All of unsuccessful reads caused by "java.net.SocketException: Original Exception : java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer"

```
2016-06-30 11:21:49,079 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.130.1.29:50010, datanodeUuid=f3d795cc-2b3b-43b9-90c3-e4157c031d2c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a99b693d-6f26-48fe-ad37-9f8162f70b22;nsid=920937379;c=0):Ignoring exception while serving BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1105510536_31776579 to /10.130.1.21:40140
2016-06-30 11:21:49,148 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.130.1.29:50010, datanodeUuid=f3d795cc-2b3b-43b9-90c3-e4157c031d2c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a99b693d-6f26-48fe-ad37-9f8162f70b22;nsid=920937379;c=0):Ignoring exception while serving BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1105510536_31776579 to /10.130.1.21:40154
2016-06-30 11:21:50,509 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.130.1.29:50010, datanodeUuid=f3d795cc-2b3b-43b9-90c3-e4157c031d2c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a99b693d-6f26-48fe-ad37-9f8162f70b22;nsid=920937379;c=0):Ignoring exception while serving BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1105510536_31776579 to /10.130.1.21:40157
2016-06-30 11:21:51,229 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.130.1.29:50010, datanodeUuid=f3d795cc-2b3b-43b9-90c3-e4157c031d2c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a99b693d-6f26-48fe-ad37-9f8162f70b22;nsid=920937379;c=0):Ignoring exception while serving BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1105510536_31776579 to /10.130.1.21:40168
2016-06-30 11:21:51,921 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.130.1.29:50010, datanodeUuid=f3d795cc-2b3b-43b9-90c3-e4157c031d2c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a99b693d-6f26-48fe-ad37-9f8162f70b22;nsid=920937379;c=0):Ignoring exception while serving BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1105510536_31776579 to /10.130.1.21:40181
2016-06-30 11:21:51,946 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.130.1.29:50010, datanodeUuid=f3d795cc-2b3b-43b9-90c3-e4157c031d2c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a99b693d-6f26-48fe-ad37-9f8162f70b22;nsid=920937379;c=0):Ignoring exception while serving BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1105510536_31776579 to /10.130.1.21:40187
2016-06-30 11:21:53,247 TRACE org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.130.1.29:50010, datanodeUuid=f3d795cc-2b3b-43b9-90c3-e4157c031d2c, infoPort=50075, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-56;cid=CID-a99b693d-6f26-48fe-ad37-9f8162f70b22;nsid=920937379;c=0):Ignoring exception while serving BP-360285305-10.130.1.11-1444619256876:blk_1105510536_31776579 to /10.130.1.21:40188
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is due to DFSInputStream do seeking before reading. If the InputStream is over read, a new request will be initiated starting from target pos.